# : error C2065: 'Lcurrent' : undeclared identifier

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I want to create a program that takes a random variable, then spits it out on the screen (windows format, not console.) But when I put the variable into the code, this happens

: error C2065: 'Lcurrent' : undeclared identifier

When I change the variable to Lcurrent, it says
: error C2065: 'LLcurrent' : undeclared identifier

How can I make it so it accepts a variable to create a window?
This is the context:

```
    while (counter < 44){
      current[1] = characters[counter];
      counter ++;
      CreateWindow(TEXT("STATIC"), TEXT(current[1]),
        WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
        0, 0, 50, 50,
        hwnd, (HMENU) NULL, NULL, NULL);
    }
```

The header files are:

windows.h

string

time.h

Comment: is `current` variable declared anywhere in your code?

Answer (score 1):

`TEXT` can only be applied to string literals. `current[1]` simply must be of type `TCHAR*`/`const TCHAR*` (or `TCHAR[]`/`const TCHAR[]`).

Answer (score 1):

`TEXT` macro prepends `L` to the argument; it can only be used to convert ANSI string literals `"..."` to Unicode string literals `L"..."`.

Since your `current` string appears to be ANSI, use `CreateWindowA`:

```
 CreateWindowA("STATIC", current[1],
    WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
    0, 0, 50, 50,
    hwnd, (HMENU) NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

(if it's a wchar_t string, use CreateWindowW with L"STATIC"; if it's TCHAR string, use CreateWindow with current[1] and TEXT("STATIC")

Comment: ANSI is a Microsoft-specific misnomer.  It usually refers to the Windows-1252 8-bit character encoding, which was never standardized by the American National Standards Institute (though it's similar to ISO 8859-1, also known as Latin-1).  The real difference between `"..."` and `L"..."` is that they refer to arrays of `char` and `wchar_t`, respectively.  In Windows, `char` is 8 bits and `wchar_t` is 16 bits, and is typically used to hold UTF-16 or UCS-2 encoded strings (there are numerous other ways of representing Unicode text).  On Linux, for example, `wchar_t` is typicall 32 bits.

Comment: Sure, you're correct. But, when applied to WinAPI and UNICODE define, ANSI is the closest term I could find to succintly describe what happens.

Comment: If I try to make your changes, then it spits out a new error. : error C2664: 'CreateWindowExA' : cannot convert parameter 3 from 'char' to 'LPCSTR'

Comment: Since I don't know what you're trying to do, I can't help you. current[1] is a character; you have to pass a string. You can pass current, or current + 1 (which is the same as &current[1]), or maybe you need to pass something else - it depends on what you want the code to do, after all.

Comment: I have an array of characters that I want to spit out from an array, this was my way of doing it. If you have a better way, **please** say so.

Comment: So you want to create a set of windows with single-character titles? Do this inside the loop: char current[2] = { characters[counter], 0 };, and pass current to CreateWindowExA.